# use / load new python module without installation

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, python-module

I am totally new to `Python`, and I have to use some modules in my code, like `numpy` and `scipy`, but I have no permission on my hosting to install new modules using `easy-install` or `pip` ( and of course I don't know how to install new modules in a directory where I have permission [ I have SSH access ] ).

I have downloaded `numpy` and used `from numpy import *` but it doesn't work. I also tried the same thing with scipy : `from scipy import *`, but it also don't work.

**How to load / use new modules in Python without installing them [ `numpy`, `scipy` .. ] ?**

Answer (score 0):

Use the --user option to easy_install or setup.py to indicate where the installation is to take place. It should point to a directory where you have write access.

Once the module has been built and installed, you then need to set the environmental variable PYTHONPATH to point to that location. When you next run the python command, you should be able to import the module.

Comment: thanks, but how to " set the environmental variable PYTHONPATH to point to that location" ?

Comment: my web hosting is running Linux

Comment: I think the AnacondaCE package is exactly what you need. I've got it running on a couple of hosted webservers now. You download the script, run it, and it installs everything in a user-writable directory. http://continuum.io/anacondace.html